# What would cause my MySQL query to hang after two results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query that I can't for the life of my get to print out on my page:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM andyasks ORDER BY date");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH);
foreach ($test as $row){
    print($row[questions]);
}
```

What this outputs is (unpredictably, to my eyes) just the first letter of **each** table field, for just the first two rows. So a 75 row table x 5 columns should show 75 "questions" lining up, but instead it shows "00WWFFAA00" which is the first letter of each cell of the first two rows. What's going on?

Comment: Can you show the table layout of andyasks? Is it indexed at all?

Comment: What that code should be doing, as far as I can see, is to fetch all the rows in the 'andyasks' table, then printing out the value of the 'questions' field of every row in one long string. Note that it should really be $row['questions'], but PHP converts questions to a string if it is not a recognized constant.

Comment: The table layout is 5 fields: "ID", "Questions", "Date", "User", "Vote". The primary key is actually the "questions" field, because I've been using "insert ignore" to not duplicate results in that field.

(I'm periodically running Twitter queries and saving the results in this table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM andyasks ORDER BY date");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    print($row["questions"]);
}
```

The reason is that you will only do one fetch with

```
$test = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH);
```

That's why you need to have it in a while loop. It fetches one row, and the while loop will terminate when there are no more rows (since it returns false when there are no more rows).

Answer (score 4):

Just to explain what's wrong with your code...

Your code is fetching only the first row into the `$test` variable. This array contains each column twice - keyed by both index and by name (which is what `MYSQL_BOTH` does). If you insert `print_r($test);` before the loop it'll dump the contents of the array, so you can see what's happening.

What your loop does is go through each column and extract its value into `$row` as a string. When you use array syntax (i.e. `$row["questions"]`) on a variable that contains a string, PHP extracts a character at the index you selected. Since `"question"` is not a number, it evaluates to 0, which is why you get the first letter of each column.

Ólafur Waage has the correct syntax for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation; I'll always prefer to learn why rather than just cut/paste. Regards.